# LEFT OUTER JOIN SUM doubles problem

Tags: php, sql

Table: Shopping

```
shop_id shop_name  shop_time
1   Brian  40
2   Brian   31
3   Tom   20
4   Brian   30
```

Table:bananas

```
banana_id  banana_amount  banana_person
1    1     Brian
2    1     Brian
```

I now want it to print:

Name: Tom | Time: 20 | Bananas: 0 
Name: Brian | Time: 101 | Bananas: 2

I used this code:

```
$result = dbquery("SELECT tz.*, tt.*,
SUM(shop_time) as shoptime,
count(banana_amount) as bananas

 FROM shopping tt
 LEFT OUTER JOIN bananas tz ON tt.shop_name=tz.banana_person
 GROUP by banana_person
LIMIT 40
");



while ($data5 = dbarray($result)) {

echo 'Name: '.$data5["shop_name"].' | Time: '.$data5["shoptime"].' | Bananas: '.$data5["bananas"].'<br>';


}
```

The problem is that I get this instead:

Name: Tom | Time: 20 | Bananas: 0
Name: Brian | Time: 202 | Bananas: 6

I just don't know how to get around this.

Comment: I don't know to be honest, Mark, sorry.

Comment: @Michale - look up source code for function dbquery, it should indicate how it connect to database, and from that it should able to tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using * is the issue (since you are using group by). 
Also, the SUM(shop_time) is being multipled by as many rows in banaanas hence you are getting 202(for two rows in bananas)

Try this  query:

```
SELECT tt.shop_name, 
           SUM(shop_time)           AS shoptime, 
           Ifnull(banana_amount, 0) AS bananas 
    FROM   shop tt 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT banana_person, 
                                   SUM(banana_amount) AS banana_amount 
                            FROM   bananas 
                            GROUP  BY banana_person) tz 
             ON tt.shop_name = tz.banana_person 
    GROUP  BY shop_name;
```

Comment: I agree: no need to downvote. The problem is caused by the usage of * and the group by (other DBMS would simply throw an error in this case). It's essentially the same solution as Mark Byers has posted

Comment: using * does not matter, the above answer is just incorrect (it return the same results as well)

Comment: @ajreal: I don't think that "* doesn't matter" is correct. It would indeed change the result. Did you check?

Comment: This solution returns the same results, unfortunately.

Comment: it's not the same as Mark's solution at all. It does select/select/aggregate rather than select/aggregate/select, and sums shop_time for each [shopping,bananas] combination produced.

Comment: @All: Updated the query. Didn;t realize the multiplicity factor because of the join and number of rows in bananas table for a shop_name

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are constructing a cross product of the two tables which multiplies the results up by the number of rows in the opposite table. To solve this first calculate the result of aggregating one of the tables in a derived table and join this aggregated result to the other table.

```
SELECT
    shop_name,
    shoptime,
    IFNULL(SUM(banana_amount), 0)
FROM (
    SELECT shop_name, SUM(shop_time) as shoptime
    FROM shopping
    GROUP BY shop_name
) tt
LEFT JOIN bananas tz ON tt.shop_name=tz.banana_person
GROUP BY shop_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
      xx.shop_name
    , xx.tot_time
    , coalesce(yy.tot_bananas, 0) as tot_bananas
from
(
    select
          shop_name
        , sum(shop_time) as tot_time
    from shopping
    group by shop_name
) as xx
left join
(
    select
          banana_person
        , sum(banana_amount) as tot_bananas
    from bananas
    group by banana_amount
) as yy on xx.shop_name = yy.banana_person
order by xx.shop_name
;
```