# Cross join ignores where clause

Tags: join, where-clause, cross-join

Table: Shopping

```
shop_id shop_building shop_person  shop_time
1   1   Brian   40
2   2   Brian   31
3   1   Tom    20
4   3   Brian   30
```

Table: buildings

```
building_id building_city
1     London
2     Newcastle 
3     London
4     London
```

Table:bananas

```
banana_id  banana_building banana_amount  banana_person
1      2     1      Brian
2      3     1       Brian
2      1     1      Tom
```

I now want it show me the amount of bananas each person has bought in London.

I used this code:

```
SELECT tt.*, tu.*, tz.*,
           SUM(shop_time)           AS shoptime, 
           Ifnull(banana_amount, 0) AS bananas 
    INNER JOIN buildings tu ON tt.shop_building=tu.building_id
    FROM   shopping tt 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT banana_person, banana_building,
                                   SUM(banana_amount) AS banana_amount 
                            FROM   bananas 
                            GROUP  BY banana_person) tz 
             ON tt.shop_person = tz.banana_person AND tt.shop_building = tz.banana_building
 WHERE tu.building_city = 'London'
    GROUP  BY shop_person;
```

But it doesn't work. It's as if I'm telling it too late, that it should only look in London, as it ignores this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what database you are using, here is a working version for mssql.
I actually rebuilt the tables to make sure it is correct.

For other database systems you'll probably have to use an other function than `ISNULL` in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT tt.shop_person,
    tt.shop_building,
    SUM(tt.shop_time) AS shoptime,
    ISNULL(SUM(tz.banana_amount), 0) AS bananas
FROM dbo.shopping tt
INNER JOIN dbo.buildings tu ON tt.shop_building = tu.building_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT banana_person, banana_building, SUM(banana_amount) AS banana_amount
        FROM bananas
        GROUP BY banana_person, banana_building) tz
    ON tt.shop_person = tz.banana_person AND tt.shop_building = tz.banana_building
WHERE (tu.building_city = 'London')
GROUP BY tt.shop_person, tt.shop_building
```

I had to add an aggregate function around `tz.banana_amount` - which one (SUM, MIN, MAX) doesn't matter.

Result:

```
shop_person shop_building shoptime bananas
Brian       1             40       0
Tom         1             20       1
Brian       3             30       1
```

I played around with different amounts in `bananas` etc. and it works correctly.

Comment: Edited my first post. I'm afraid I need the shopping table as well though, so the code has to look pretty similar to the one I have in the first post (Reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639722/left-outer-join-sum-doubles-problem)

Comment: Actually, I'd not include any * as select parameters in a query with a group by clause. What do you mean by "pretty"?

Comment: btw, the subquery tz is still missing the banana_building column

Comment: By "Pretty" I mean that it obviously shouldn't look identical to my code as my code doesn't work. But if possible it needs to be as close as possible. Edited properly this time :)

Comment: IT's not identical - you still don't have banana_building in the group by clause of your subquery.

Comment: For some reason I need the * after 'tz.' at the beginning. I tried replacing it with 'tz.banana_id, tz.banana_person, tz.banana_building, tz.banana_amount' but that just returns zeros.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I completely misunderstood your answer. I thought you were just quoting my code first and then showing your suggestion.

Anyway, I'm afraid your answer with the added Group by clause doesn't work either. It only counts some of bananas.

Comment: Ok, I removed the second query, and adjusted select and group by params of your modified query

Comment: Again, no luck. Removing the 'tz.*' from the top makes banana_amount return zeros. Grouping twice for some reason reduces the amount significant.

Comment: I actually rebuilt your tables, take a look at this version of the answer (replace ISNULL with your function)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
SELECT 
    s.shop_person, sum(b.banana_amount) as Amt, , sum(shop_time) as TimeAmt
FROM bananas b
    INNER JOIN buildings bu ON b.banana_building = bu.building_id
    INNER JOIN shopping s ON bu.building_id = s.shop_building
WHERE
    bu.building_city = N'London'
GROUP BY s.shop_person
```

This query is different, but it does what you want - 'the amount of bananas each person has bought in London'

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, it still ignores it and counts everything in the bananas table.

Comment: Is mentioned query ok for you?

Comment: Afraid not, as I need the code to be fairly similar to the one I posted in the OP, if possible (Reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639722/left-outer-join-sum-doubles-problem)

Comment: Hmmmm... So, pls, define what query do you want to see.